# Как получить значение переменной базового класса в производном?

Tags: c++

```
class FirstClass {
    protected:
        char* str_value;
}

class SecondClass : FirstClass {
    public:
        SecondClass() : FirstClass (str_value)
        {}
};
```

Как получить значение `str_value` базового класса?

**UPDATE**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

class FirstClass {
    protected:
        char* str_value;
    public:
        FirstClass() {}

        FirstClass(const char* value) {
            set(value);
        }

        FirstClass(const FirstClass &obj){};

        ~FirstClass() {delete[] str_value;}

    void set(const char* value) {
        delete[] str_value;
        str_value = new char[strlen(value)+1];
        strcpy(str_value, value);
    }

    const char* get() {
        return str_value;
    }
};

class SecondClass : FirstClass {
    public:
        SecondClass(const char* str_value) : FirstClass (str_value) {}
 };

int main() {
    FirstClass F_object("aaaaaaaaaa");

    F_object.set("bbbbbbbbbb");

    printf("%s", F_object.get());

    FirstClass F_object2 = F_object;

    SecondClass S_object();

    S_object.get();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы, похоже, запутались...

Вам нужно создать `SecondClass` с какой-то строкой в `FirstClass`? Для этого нужно эту строку *не получить* от `FirstClass`, а передать:

```
SecondClass::SecondClass(const char* str)
:FirstClass(str) {}
```

А если вам потом в `SecondClass` нужно к ней обратиться - то это поле у вас объявлено как `protected`, так что просто по имени...

**Update**

Ваши ошибки.

1. Надо так:

   ```
   FirstClass(const char* value)
   :str_value(0)                  // ВАЖНО!!!
   {
       set(value);
   }
   ```
2. ```
   FirstClass(const FirstClass &obj)
   :str_value(0)                  // ВАЖНО!!!
   {
       set(obj.str_value);
   };
   ```
3. Лучше так (`const` после `get()`)

   ```
   const char* get() const
   {
       return str_value;
   }
   ```
4. Наследование должно быть **открытое**!

   ```
   class SecondClass : public FirstClass
   ```
5. Вот это -

   ```
   SecondClass S_object();
   ```

   на  самом деле не объект `S_object`, а *объявление функции* `S_object`, которая не принимает параметров и возвращает `SecondClass`. Пишите просто -

   ```
   SecondClass S_object;
   ```

   ну, или

   ```
   SecondClass S_object{};
   ```

   (Но, насколько я помню, у вас древний компилятор и `{}` он может и не пропустить.)

И еще - ваш конструктор по умолчанию угробит программу, потому что в `str_value` будет мусор, который захочет удалить декструктор. Лучше выбросьте конструктор по умолчанию вовсе, и сделайте таковым обычный конструктор, предоставляя значение по умолчанию, вроде

```
    FirstClass(const char* value = "")
    :str_value(0)                  // ВАЖНО!!!
    {
        set(value);
    }

    SecondClass(const char* str_value = "") : FirstClass (str_value) {}
```

Comment: Создал конструктор: SecondClass(const char* str_value) : FirstClass (str_value) {}. Создаю экземпляр: SecondClass S_object();. При вызове метода GET который унаследовался от базового выдаёт ошибку: request for member 'get' in 'S_object', which is of non-class type 'SecondClass()'|. Метод:const char* get() {
        return str_value;
    }

Comment: Я что-то не так делаю.

Comment: Приведите полный исходник, пожалуйста.

Comment: я обновил вопрос

Comment: См. обновленный ответ.

Comment: Всё вроде получилось, всё сделал как Вы сказали, но при вызове метода get я ничего не получаю. Почему так происходит? Я же по идее должен получить значение базового класса? Или я не получаю значение и вывожу пустоту которую инициализировал в конструкторе.

Comment: Что значит - не получаю? А как вы себе представляете это получение? Присвойте переменной это значение и посмотрите, например. Или выведите на экран. Только если вы взяли мой текст - то по умолчанию там пустая строка. Задайте что-нибудь и посмотрите - например, `SecondClass S_object("Object"); cout << S_object.get() << endl;`

Comment: Что значит - не получаю? А как вы себе представляете это получение? Присвойте переменной это значение и посмотрите, например. Или выведите на экран. Только если вы взяли мой текст - то по умолчанию там пустая строка. Задайте что-нибудь и посмотрите - например, `SecondClass S_object("Object"); cout << S_object.get() << endl;`

Comment: Реализовать в производном классе метод – поиска и удаления самого короткого слова в строке базового класса. А я даже получить не могу. Получается только если при объявлении производного класса я передам ему GET из базового. А если я изменю его в производном то в базовом ничего не измениться. Нету связи. Не понимаю

Comment: Ну не хочу я все решать за вас... Работайте просто с `str_value` - как делали бы это в базовом классе. Раз вы его меняете, то наше `get()` не годится - потому что оно возвращает указатель на строку, которую нельзя менять.

Comment: Хорошо, но в итоге, я так и не получил в производном классе значение базового

Comment: Все, я уже разжевал до последнего. Дальше могу посоветовать только идти куда-то типа [Решалки](http://www.reshaem.net/?cGFydG5lcj03OTIy), там все сделают за вас. Здесь я пас. Делать за вас я не буду, а вы понять не хотите...

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68190/discussion-between-aaa-and-harry).

Answer (score 1):

Он у Вас в `protected` секции, следовательно, доступ к нему есть из производного класса. Если работаете в студии, можете написать `this->`, после чего у Вас появится выпадающий список видимых имен. Здесь можете обращаться просто по имени. И подправьте код в конструкторе производного класса и дополните в базовом классе, как в ответе Harry.